# Importing data to python from excel

Tags: python

I am trying to import an excel data to python and from this data I need to create a 20x20 matrix.The problem is I cannot import data or even I do I am not sure how to convort it to the matrix. I am using anaconda python (also I have normal python with no packages).

I tried several codes that I saw here or I watched many videos but none of them worked.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2T7w.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBOgO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcWKd.png)

`8  2   22  97  38  15  0   40  0   75  4   5   7   78  52  12  50  77  91  8
49  49  99  40  17  81  18  57  60  87  17  40  98  43  69  48  4   56  62  0
81  49  31  73  55  79  14  29  93  71  40  67  53  88  30  3   49  13  36  65
52  70  95  23  4   60  11  42  69  24  68  56  1   32  56  71  37  2   36  91
22  31  16  71  51  67  63  89  41  92  36  54  22  40  40  28  66  33  13  80
24  47  32  60  99  3   45  2   44  75  33  53  78  36  84  20  35  17  12  50
32  98  81  28  64  23  67  10  26  38  40  67  59  54  70  66  18  38  64  70
67  26  20  68  2   62  12  20  95  63  94  39  63  8   40  91  66  49  94  21
24  55  58  5   66  73  99  26  97  17  78  78  96  83  14  88  34  89  63  72
21  36  23  9   75  0   76  44  20  45  35  14  0   61  33  97  34  31  33  95
78  17  53  28  22  75  31  67  15  94  3   80  4   62  16  14  9   53  56  92
16  39  5   42  96  35  31  47  55  58  88  24  0   17  54  24  36  29  85  57
86  56  0   48  35  71  89  7   5   44  44  37  44  60  21  58  51  54  17  58
19  80  81  68  5   94  47  69  28  73  92  13  86  52  17  77  4   89  55  40
4   52  8   83  97  35  99  16  7   97  57  32  16  26  26  79  33  27  98  66
88  36  68  87  57  62  20  72  3   46  33  67  46  55  12  32  63  93  53  69
4   42  16  73  38  25  39  11  24  94  72  18  8   46  29  32  40  62  76  36
20  69  36  41  72  30  23  88  34  62  99  69  82  67  59  85  74  4   36  16
20  73  35  29  78  31  90  1   74  31  49  71  48  86  81  16  23  57  5   54
1   70  54  71  83  51  54  69  16  92  33  48  61  43  52  1   89  19  67  48`

Comment: Paste your code so we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `pandas` for this which is preinstalled in the anaconda distribution. If your excel sheet has the correct form do the following

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(path_of_your_file_as_string, sheetname='insert_sheetname_here')
```

In case of problems with invalid characters try to use `pd.read_excel(r'insert_path_here', sheetname='insert_sheetname_here')`. To finally convert it to matrix (if one is not convenient with pandas dataframes) one can use

```
matrix = np.array(df)
```

Comment: I did import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(‪C:/Users/Arman/Desktop/as.xlsx, sheetname='as')

Comment: your path must be a string

Comment: still doenst work ? import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(‪"C:/Users/Arman/Desktop/as.xlsx", sheetname='as')        SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Comment: is your sheet named 'as' or just the excel file? Try to delete sheetname, so just use

`df = pd.read_excel(path_of_your_file_as_string)`

Comment: I saved it like "as" I tried and still get the same error I also changed my sheet name and tried again but again same error   import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(‪"C:\Users\Arman\Desktop\as.xlsx", sheetname='sheet1')

Comment: File "<ipython-input-7-196660463665>", line 3
    df = pd.read_excel(‪"C:\Users\Arman\Desktop\as.xlsx", sheetname='sheet1')
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Comment: use "\\" instead of "\". This can be a problem in Windows systems

Comment: İt gives the same error..Is there an another way maybe ?

Comment: 8 2 22 97 38 15 0 40 0
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93
52 70 95 23 4 60 11 42 69
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41
24 47 32 60 99 3 45 2 44
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26
67 26 20 68 2 62 12 20 95
İts 20x20 so larger of this...

Comment: It doenst look like this actaully think each number in each cell and 20x20

Comment: please put your excel lines in code quotes! And post it in your question

Comment: I ll post images and etc. A moment please

Comment: no images please, it should be possible to copy the lines you wrote in code quotes!

Comment: I think this will be more helpfull

Comment: use raw strings r"C:\Users\Arman\Desktop\as.xlsx" or "\\" instead of "\" as I already told you!

Comment: it worked..I tried that last time and it seemed didnt worked..I didnt get it..Okay I solved it. Now I have to convert this into the matrix Thanks btw

Comment: you can either go with the dataframe, which is very similar to a matrix or use np.array(df) to convert it to a numpy matrix

Comment: I ll try thanks a lot if something happens I post here